# How to differentiate $\sum_{i}(y_i-t_i)^2$ by $y$?

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, derivatives, vectors

$L=\sum_{i}(y_i-t_i)^2$

I want to differentiate $L$ by $y$.
Unfortunately I didn't learn this material, so a wild guess would be:

$(1) \frac{dL}{dy}=\frac{d}{dy} (\vec{y}\cdot \vec{y}^T -2\cdot \vec{y} \cdot \vec{t}^T + \vec{t} \cdot \vec{t})$

From here I got to:
$=2\vec{y}-2\vec{t}^T$

But I guess this not ok, because the dimensions are not equal. This means I needed to do:

$(2) \frac{dL}{dy}=\frac{d}{dy} \vec{y}\cdot \vec{y}^T -2\cdot \vec{t} \cdot \vec{y}^T + \vec{t} \cdot \vec{t}$

And then I'll get $=2\vec{y}-2\vec{t}$ which is the correct answer I think.

I switched places because it suited me better, but I don't think that math works that way. I'm sure there is an algorithm for these operations. 
How I was supposed to know that I should of opened it like in $(2)$ and not like $(1)$ ?

Comment: $y=(y_1,y_2,\ldots,y_n)$?

Comment: @MathOverview Yes sorry

Comment: Question. In equality "(1)" would not $ \vec{t}\cdot \vec{t}^T $ be in place of $ \vec{t}\cdot\vec{t}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}\frac{\partial L}{\partial y_j}&=\frac{\partial }{\partial y_j} \sum_i (y_i-t_i)^2\\&= \frac{\partial }{\partial y_j} \left[(y_j-t_j)^2 + \sum_{i \ne j} (y_i-t_i)^2\right]\\&= \frac{\partial }{\partial y_j} \left[(y_j-t_j)^2\right] + \left[\frac{\partial}{\partial y_j} \sum_{i \ne j} (y_i-t_i)^2\right] 
\\&=2(y_j-t_j) \frac{\partial (y_j-t_j)}{\partial y_j }+0\\&=2(y_j-t_j) \end{align}

Hence $$\nabla_y L=2(y-t)$$

Note that $y^Tt=t^Ty$, here all my vectors are column vectors.

Comment: Care to explain why it is equal to $2(y_j-t_j) \frac{\partial (y_j-t_j)}{\partial y_j }$ ?
I guess by chain rule? Can you please write down the full calculation?

Comment: I have added more details.

Comment: Thanks! Just checking: it is $\frac{\partial (y_j-t_j)}{\partial y_j }$ because you are actually doing $\frac{L}{\partial (y_j-t_j)} \cdot \frac{\partial (y_j-t_j)}{\partial y_j }$ Right?

Comment: yup, that is just chain rule.